# Async function in $parsers doesn't update $modelValue

Tags: angularjs

Was wondering how I should handle async functions in `$parsers`.
The below code doesn't update the scope.

I'm using AngularJS 1.2 so can't make use of the new and fancy 1.3 features.

http://plnkr.co/edit/uk9VMipYNphzk8l7p9iZ?p=preview

**Markup:**

```
<input type="text" name="test" ng-model="test" parse>
```

**Directive:**

```
app.directive('parse', function($timeout) {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(viewValue) {
        $timeout(function() {
          return viewValue;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Can you detail you scenario a bit. You can call $setViewValue(value); of model controller to update model data, but the input content does not change.

Comment: You cannot do that. Can you shed more context?

Comment: It's a directive for making an async lookup for availability of the entered value. I basically want $asyncValidators from angular v1.3, but I'm stuck with v1.2 :(
I have a "workaround" but wanted to know how to correctly handle this issue :)

The work around is just returning the viewValue no matter what. So `function (viewValue) { validatorAsync(viewValue); return viewValue; }`

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for async validation function, I did something like that some time ago and release it as a library. Check the custom-remote-validator [directive here](https://github.com/technovert/angular-validation).

The basic idea was use ngModelController $setValidity after receiving validation result from server. This is the directive source code

```
.directive('customRemoteValidator', [function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elm, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
            var validateFunctionNames = attr["remoteValidateFunctions"].split(",");
            var validatorNames = attr["customRemoteValidator"].split(",");
            ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(function (value) {
                angular.forEach(validateFunctionNames, function (functionName, index) {
                    if (!scope[functionName]) {
                        console.log('There is no function with ' + functionName + ' available on the scope. Please make sure the function exists on current scope or its parent.');
                    } else {
                        var result = scope[functionName](value);
                        if (result.then) {
                            result.then(function (data) { //For promise type result object
                                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(validatorNames[index], data);
                            }, function (error) {
                                ngModelCtrl.$setValidity(validatorNames[index], false);
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
                return value;
            });
        }
    };
}])
```